# Shortest path problem from A to B on routing engines

Tags: routing, graph, dijkstra

I am in the process of creating a routing engine. I have encountered the following problem. Lets say the user gives a point A and point B and expects to get the A->B shortest path. I am using simple Dijkstra for now.

Let's say that I can somehow find the `(latitudeA, longitudeA)` and `(latitudeB, longitudeB)` coordinates, which are the closest coordinates to the A and B points that the user inputted. From those coordinates I could then also find the `nodeA_ID` and `nodeB_ID` on the graph. The problem is that for those nodes it is very likely that the A->B path doesn't exist at all. For example, if node A was only part of a one-way road that went to the opposite direction that the user wanted to go to.

However, a **A'** and **B'** must exist, *very close* to A and B respectively, so that the **A'->B'** path exists. So the routing engine should try and find that **A'->B'** path instead.

Also, that **A'->B'** path might not even be **optimal**. There could have been a **A''->B''** path, where A'' and B'' were only a couple of meters away from A and B. So the routing engine should find the **A''->B''** optimal path instead.

How do routing engines handle this situation ?

Comment: Same question was also posted on Help OSM: https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/49117/shortest-path-problem-from-a-to-b-on-routing-engines

Comment: @mmd I thought I would post it on that website too. Why ? Is it wrong ? Its not related to stackexchange, is it ?

Comment: If you post the same question on several sites, you're wasting everyones time. That's why it is generally frowned upon and considered bad etiquette.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get rid of such subnetworks otherwise it is harder as you'll need to decide for a 'cost factor' such distances need to be multiplied with.

E.g. if you have A' and A'' and B' and B'' there are obviously 4 possible combinations with different **distances** and 4 potential different paths with different **costs** (e.g. distance, time or fuel costs) so you have different units which you need to multiply with the cost factor to include both in the calculation to get the 'best' overall path.

> For example, if node A was only part of a one-way road that went 
>   to the opposite direction that the user wanted to go to.

IMO the intend of the user should be specified e.g. with a heading or a previously tracked GPS point. Judging just from the resulting path(s) is really hard as outlined above especially for motorways where a minor GPS flaw could result in completely different results.

Answer (score 0):

If the implementation of Dijkstra have good performance for the data in use, You may try to:

- get n nodes closest to A;
- get n nodes closest to B;

For each collection, points could be on different segments with some buffer. For (a sql) example: `ST_DWithin Order by ST_Distance LIMIT n`...)

Calculate n*n Dijkstra possibles routes e keep the best one.